# How to call ajax on input box rather than select box with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, duplicates, find

> I am working on code igniter. i have one dynamic form where i want to
>   populate some data with the help of one dropdown list. I want to
>   display that data into input box rather than another option value. I
>   got one online code that populate data with ajax call into another
>   select box its working for me. but if i used input box then its not
>   working for me.

My ajax call :

```
var baseURL= "<?php echo base_url();?>"; 
  $(document).ready(function()
  {    
    $('#employee').change(function(){
      var EMPLOYEE_ID = $(this).val();
      // AJAX request
      $.ajax({        
        url:'<?php echo base_url()?>/Responsible/getEmpData',
        method: 'post',
        data: {EMPLOYEE_ID :EMPLOYEE_ID },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
        alert(response);
          // Remove options 
          $('#sel_depart').find('input').not(':first').remove();          
          $.each(response,function(index,data){
             //$('#sel_depart').append('<option value="'+data['DETAIL_ID']+'">'+data['NI_NUMBER']+'</option>');
             $('#sel_depart').append('<input type="text" class="span8" name="ni_number" value="'+data['NI_NUMBER']+'"/>');

          });
        }
     });
   });
 });
```

As you can view my commented code of option value is working.I am trying to same thing on input box but my `$('#sel_depart').find('input').not(':first').remove();`  this line is not working.

My input box:

`<input id='sel_depart' type="text" class="span8" name='ni_number' value=""/>`

My controller :

```
public function getEmpData()
    { 
      $postData = $this->input->post();    
      $this->load->model('Pay_slips_model');    
      $data = $this->pay_slips->getEmpData($postData);
      echo json_encode($data); 
    }
```

Model :

```
public function getEmpData($postData)
            {
                $response = array();        
                $this->db->select('ed.DETAIL_ID,ed.NI_NUMBER');
                $this->db->where('EMPLOYEE_ID', $postData['EMPLOYEE_ID']);
                $q = $this->db->get('employee_details ed');
                $response = $q->result_array();
                return $response;
            }
```

I am getting duplicate or multiple `NI_NUMBER` for each `EMPLOYEE_ID`.In my table `employee_details` I am having only one `NI_NUMBER` for each `EMPLOYEE_ID`.  If i inspect my input box after ajax call i can see duplicate data in input box but its not showing on form.What is is the solution for both the problems.

1. Not able to display data in input box rather than select box.
2. how to prevent from duplicate rows from table.

Comment: To insert a value in input box simply put:  $('#sel_depart').val(data['NI_NUMBER']);

Comment: maybe using blur function in the input and make your ajax call synchronous, (not using async: false)